# Netplan config with IPv4 and IPV6

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I am trying to update a server with IPv4 and IPv6 addresses to 22.04.1.  I was trying to get netplan updated and it wanted routes, but I was having some trouble getting the config correct and lost network on the server.  The netplan examples don't have much in the way of IPv6 examples and I've not found anything helpful while searching.

```
    network:
  version: 2
#  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/18
        - aaaa:aaaa:aaa:aa::aaa:aaaa/64
      gateway4: 111.111.1.1
      gateway6: bbbb:bbbb:bbb:bb::b
      nameservers:
        addresses: 
#quad 9 DNS servers
          - 9.9.9.9
          - 149.112.112.112
          - 2620:fe::fe 
          - 2620:fe::9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A netplan file with ipv6 looks like

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      critical: true
      dhcp-identifier: mac
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.20/26
        - 2001:0db8:100:2::20/64
      routes:
        - to: default    # defaut ipv4
          via: 192.168.1.1
        - to: "::/0"      # defaut ipv6
          via: "2001:0db8:100:2::1"
          on-link: true

  nameservers:
    addresses:
    - 192.168.1.1
    - 2001:0db8:100:2::1
```

please note gateway4 and gateway6 are deprecated. Use regulary routes as shown.

Comment: I had to edit the nameserver section, and then I got this warning:

** (generate:4248): WARNING **: 15:43:42.578: Problem encountered while validating default route consistency.Please set up multiple routing tables and use `routing-policy` instead.
Error: Conflicting default route declarations for IPv4 (table: main, metric: default), first declared in enp2s0 but also in eth0

Comment: You may need to adopt some settings like  interface names to your needs. I posted a sample, not a full solution for you.

Comment: I think I found part of the issue - I had setup a strongswan VPN server on the box as well, and it has another IP address on eth0, which is probably causing the conflict

Comment: perfect, if you want to get support, it makes sense to provide as much info as possible.

Comment: I didn't catch it until I had logged back in on another terminal and it displayed the IP address.